# Need help identifying this 8" silicon wafer

Tags: identification, silicon

I just received this silicon wafer that I bought off of eBay to decorate my wall, but I'm curious as to what the chips would be used for. I reached out to the seller, but they didn't know.

The wafer has D120807-D6 marked on the edge. Not sure if that's a serial number or chip designation. I tried googling but wasn't able to come up with anything.

| **Full wafer** | **Close-up of one of the dice** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Full wafer] | [image: Close-up of one of the dice] |

Comment: Get a microscope and see if the mask had a company and part number on it.

Comment: That's probably a lot number, not anything to do with what the actual ICs on it are. Your picture is somewhat blurry (it's *very* hard to take good sharp pictures of dice (not "dies", incidentally) without some sort of camera mount) but it looks like some sort of complex logic, possibly a microcontroller, PLD, or memory? This is a very slightly educated guess, though.

Comment: Don't think it's pure memory - too many odd shaped structures.  Probably not an FPGA for the same reason.  May be some type of SoC (System on Chip).  The rectangular structures could be memory of some sort.

Comment: D120807 lookd like a date code

Comment: looks like flying over the Prairies farmland near Winnipeg.

Comment: Looks like some sort of CPU/MCU.  Decoder and ALU at top center, pROM or dRAM at bottom center, registers or RAM at bottom right?

Comment: Just an aside, the dice with the black dots in the center probably failed testing.

Comment: Is the ruler in inches? If that's the case, the dies are huge. Intel i7 processors are typically smaller than this. So they probably are very powerful SoCs / processors.